# Group $G$ s.t. $x^5y^3=x^8y^5=e$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be group with identity $e$, and $x, y$ be two elements of $G$ satisfying $x^5y^3=x^8y^5=e$. Which of following is true?

1. $x=e$, $y=e$;
2. $x=e$, $y \ne e$;
3. $x \ne e$, $y=e$;
4. $x\ne e$, $y \ne e$.

Comment: hint: $e=x^8y^5=x^3(x^5y^3)y^2=x^3y^2$ You can apply this kind of reasoning over and over to get new identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $x^5y^3=x^8y^5$ and multiply it with $x^{-5}$ to the left and with $y^{-3}$ to the right.  We get $e=x^3y^2$ and therefore $x^3y^2=x^5y^3=e$
By the same way we get to $e=x^2y=x^3y$ and again this yields $x=e$
Replacing in the initial identity we get $y^3=y^5=e$ and through the same approach we get to $y=e$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not terribly well formulated, in my humble opinion.

In fact, the statement of the problem implies that one of the four claims must hold true. Since the trivial groups trivially satisfies the hypothesis, the first claim must be the right one.

It would be a different matter if the formulation had been

> Let $G$ be a group, and $x, y \in G$. Suppose $ x^5y^3=x^8y^5=e $. Prove that $x = y = e$.

This is very well solved in a previous answer.